# How to eliminate items which cause errors in the list in Python

Tags: python, list, error-handling

The following script pulls some stock-related info from Bloomberg for every stock in the list "tickers".  I need help changing the code so it automatically skips stock symbols which cause error.   Can this be done? Thanks in advance!

```
#ticker list
tickers = index_members

#append tickers
for ticker in tickers: 
    request.append("securities", ticker)

#fields list
fields = ['NAME','GICS_SECTOR_NAME','GICS_INDUSTRY_NAME']

#append fields 
for field in fields: 
    request.append("fields", field)

#send request 
session.sendRequest(request) 

#create dataframe 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Ticker', 'NAME','GICS_SECTOR_NAME','GICS_INDUSTRY_NAME'])

endReached = False 
while endReached == False: 
    ev = session.nextEvent() 
    if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE or ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.PARTIAL_RESPONSE: 
        for msg in ev: 
            #entire response 
            security_table = msg.getElement("securityData")
            
            for i in range(0, security_table.numValues()): #number of securities in request 
                security_data = security_table.getValue(i) # full response for each ticker 
                field_data = security_data.getElement("fieldData") # field data only for each ticker 
                
                sec = security_data.getElement("security").getValue() #ticker 
                field_1 = [x.getValue() for x in field_data.elements()][0] #field 1: name
                field_2 = [x.getValue() for x in field_data.elements()][1] #field 2: gics_sector_name
                field_3 = [x.getValue() for x in field_data.elements()][2] #field 3: gics_industry_name
                
                table = {'Ticker': sec, 'NAME':field_1,'GICS_SECTOR_NAME':field_2,'GICS_INDUSTRY_NAME':field_3}  #dict to map tickers to values 
                df = df.append(table, ignore_index=True) # add to dataframe 
            
            
    if ev.eventType() == blpapi.Event.RESPONSE: 
        endReached = True
```

Comment: Do they rise an exception? if so, try to wrap the code, that produces it in a `try ... except` block to handle the exception properly.

Comment: Btw. I think you should be kind and add a `time.sleep` statement somewhere to put not too much stress on the server.